# What to do when employees max out on experience and no longer gain any?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I can't seem to find any reference to this behavior anywhere, so I'm not even sure if it might be a bug. Either way, I have an employee who hasn't gained any experience for the past 4 or 5 games I've made, and is just sitting halfway into level 3.

I've tried training him in various things to see if I can get him unstuck, but to no avail. Do I need to fire him and rehire someone better? If this is the case and it's not a bug, how do I know what level I can expect other employees to cap out at?

Thanks!

Comment: I've never had this happen, so it sounds like a bug. Level 3 is nowhere near the maximum I've had employees at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone ever winds up here with the same problem:

Not a bug... turns out that this employee was actually just at 0% efficiency. Some combination of me being unobservant, and my screen brightness meant that I'd missed the bar going down, and then it had ended up being near-invisible when empty.

Lesson learned!

Comment: +1 - now I know what happened. I fired him because I thought he's not improving any more :).